# No ClassTag available for T -- not for Array

Tags: scala

Here is a part of code involving akka:

```
abstract class AkkaBaseClass[T <: AkkaClass1, U <: Loger] extends Actor {

  protected val val1 = context.actorOf(Props[T])
  protected val val2 = context.actorOf(Props[U])

  def receive = {
    case "test" => {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(Config.timeout seconds)
      val future = val1 ? "request"
      val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[List[ActorRef]]
      sender ! result
    }


    case "log" => val2 ! "log"
  }

class AkkaClass1 extends Actor { .... }


trait Loger extends Actor { ..... }
```

There are 2 errors:

```
No ClassTag available for T and No ClassTag available for U
```

But `T` and `U` are not arrays. What do I do about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though you omitted the place where the errors took place, I'm guessing they are happening at `Props`. It is probably the case that `Props` take an implicit `ClassTag` as a parameter, particularly since it doesn't take any other parameter. And though a `ClassTag` is used by array creation, it can also be used for other things, such as getting a `Class` that can then be used to instantiate classes by reflection, or as a reference when comparing instances received.

To solve it, declare `AkkaBaseClass` like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class AkkaBaseClass[T <: AkkaClass1 : ClassTag, U <: Loger : ClassTag] extends Actor {
```

Comment: does `T` have to implement `ClassTag` after that?

Comment: @MariusKavansky `T` doesn't have to implement at a `ClassTag`. Instead, there must be an implicit instance of `ClassTag[T]` available in scope at call site. The scala compiler can generate that for any concrete type, but if the call site is also using an abstract type like a type parameter, then the call site will also require an implicit `ClassTag` for it.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not block on Futures if not *required*:

Here's a solution to your problem.

```
abstract class AkkaBaseClass[T <: AkkaClass1 : ClassTag, U <: Loger : ClassTag] extends Actor {

  protected val val1 = context.actorOf(Props[T])
  protected val val2 = context.actorOf(Props[U])

  def receive = {
    case "test" => val1 forward "request"
    case  "log" => val2 ! "log"
  }

class AkkaClass1 extends Actor { .... }


trait Loger extends Actor { ..... }
```

Comment: why do you think it's not required? that's just a simple version of the code.

Comment: Updated the example with ClassTags. As for the blocking, if it is not needed in the example, why is it in the example?

Comment: but neither AkkaClass1 no Loger implement ClassTag, do they? But they will have to.

Comment: ":" is a context bound, it is effectively an implicit parameter:

"class Foo[T : ClassTag]" is equivalent to "class Foo[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T])"